# Custom text under Add to cart but not on side in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce I am using the following code to add a custom text under add to cart:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
    // Echo content.
    echo '<div  style="font-size:10px;"><em>(*Contact us for bulk purchase enquiry)</em></div>';
}
```

But It is displayed in one line like in this screenshot:

[image]

How can I have it under the add to cart button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use a `<br slyle="clear:both;">` that has a slyling `clear` argument set to `both`, to stop the floating styling behavior:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
    // Echo content.
    echo '<br slyle="clear:both;"><div  style="font-size:10px;"><em>(*Contact us for bulk purchase enquiry)</em></div>';
}
```

It should work...

Answer (score 1):

Just Wrape the Text with `<div>` as follow:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_addtocart_button_func');

function content_after_addtocart_button_func()
{

    // Echo content.
    echo '<div>(*Contact us for bulk purchase enquiry)</div>';
}
```

or you can use `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form` as follow:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'content_after_addtocart_button_func');

function content_after_addtocart_button_func()
{

// Echo content.
     echo '<div>(*Contact us for bulk purchase enquiry)</div>';
}
```

Comment: woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form worked well for my use, thank you.